# Function does not use variable path

Tags: python, function, path

I have a function that fills a path variable after receiving input from user (GUI - user clicks Select folder and selects it).
Since I used the global "option" (global path), the variable can be printed with print(path).
So, the value of the variable does not get lost.

The second part of the software is a function that renames files based on a preset rule.
This function works well when run separately (meaning I only use this code) but sees only in the folder it resides.

The scope of the GUI is to select folders from other parts of the `filesystem` and make use of the renaming function. The second function should take the path variable and use it to target the proper folder. I used `os.sep` to replace forward slash to backslash (Windows).

The problem is that the path does not get to the second function or I defined the function in a way that it will not use path when together with the GUI code.

That second function starts with:

```
def beautify():
    for  file in os.listdir(path):
        fname, fext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if not file.find(".py"):
            if fname.find(".") > 0:
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, fname.replace(".", " ") + fext))
```

Tried manipulating path format in different ways. But, after I returned to the original code and saw that `print()` can spit out the path outside the first function, I stopped forcing that way.
Then, I tried juggling with `os.walk` but with no success.

Comment: The easy answer here is to not use global variables, but there isn't enough of your code here to suggest a specific alternate approach.

Comment: If it's a global variable, you should be able to use `path` in the `beautify()` function.

Comment: BTW, why not use `if fext != ".py":` and `if "." in fname:`?

Comment: Please post a [mre] so we can see how you're setting the global variable.

Comment: Updated original post with more code (what's missing is more search and reaplce operations, using same syntax).

Comment: The solution was this:
if fext != ".py" and fname.find(".") > 0:
Thank you!
How can I mark your answer correct?
This platform kills me.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer, not as a comment or part of the question. Then you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: There is no option for that.
At least I can't see any.